# Building workflow forms with just Windows Sharepoint Services (WSS 3.0)

Tags: sharepoint

We are happy with WSS 3.0 and the only thing that we can't do is that building a workflow form.

We are thinking to use custom ASP.NET coding as in separate stand-alone page or maybe as a webpart. We heard about InfoPath but this is not available unless upgrading to MOSS.

I am just wondering what other people have done in regards to this. MOSS is not really an option at this stage.

I am appreciated your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

We've done a number of custom ASP.NET pages, it's pretty easy when you get the hang of it

Comment: Are you doing it as seperate ASP.NET page or as webpart?

Comment: Separate ASP.NET, you cannot do it as a web part, but attach the page to SP master page, it will look just like SP